# Find the tangent space $TcM$ and provide a basis for it

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds

Let $c=(0,1,2)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto f(x,y,z):= x^2+y^2+z^2-5$. Let $M:=f^{-1}(0)$. Find the tangent space $T_cM$ and provide a basis for it.

### My attempt

The matrix associated with the differential will be a $(3\times 1)$ matrix given by

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \partial_1f       & \partial_2f  & \partial_3f 
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
    2x       & 2y  & 2z 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Evaluated at $c=(0,1,2)$, it's

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 2  & 4 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The columns here are basis of the tangent space. Basis = $\{2\vec{e}_2,4\vec{e}_3\}$.

I am pretty sure I am doing the problem wrong because I don't know how to apply $M:=f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: The tangent plane $T_cM$ is given by the kernel of the differential $df$.

Comment: is my basis correct? @JohnMa

Comment: Is $2\vec e_2$ lying in the kernel of $df$?

Comment: @JohnMa Well the kernal of $\partial f$ is just setting it equal to zero right? so $2x +2y + 2z=0$ but then we have to evaluate it at $c$ so we get the matrix [0 2 4] and the columns are a basis

Comment: @JohnMa ok now I get that this does not equal the zero vector. Now what?

Comment: You need to find two vectors (which is a basis of $T_cM$) $(a_1, b_1, c_1), (a_2, b_2, c_2)$ so that they both satisfy $2y + 4z  =0$ (that is, they both lie in the kernel).