# Find the $T_cM$ and provide a basis for it if $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto f(x,y,z):= x^3+y^2-z^2$...

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds

Let $c=(0,1,1)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto f(x,y,z):= x^3+y^2-z^2$. Let $M:=f^{-1}(0)$. Find the $T_cM$ and provide a basis for it.

### My attempt:

Since $M:=f^{-1}(0)$ and  $f$ is mapped to $0$ at $c=(0,1,1)$.

Taking the differential: matrix will be a $(1\times 3)$ (since $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$).

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \partial_1f       & \partial_2f  & \partial_3f
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
    3x^2       & 2y  & -2z
\end{bmatrix}$$

Evaluated at $c=(0,1,1)$,

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 2  & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$

The columns of this matrix is form a basis of the tangent space, so basis = $\{2\vec{e}_2,-2\vec{e}_3\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$M = \{(x,y,z): f(x,y,z) = 0\}$$

Since $\nabla f(c) \not = \textbf{0}$ then by the implicit function theorem, we can choose $\gamma(t)$ to be a smooth curve with $\gamma(0) = c$. In particular, it will be advantageous to note $f(\gamma(t)) = 0$. Now we use the chain rule.

$$0=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0} f(\gamma(t)) = \nabla f(c) \cdot \gamma'(0)$$

And so $\nabla f(c) \perp v$ for all $v \in T_cM$. We know from calculus that an equation of this plane with normal $\nabla f(c)$ and containing $c$ is given by,

$$ \nabla f(c) \cdot \underbrace{\langle \textbf{x} - c\rangle}_{\in\  T_cM} = 0$$

For a basis, from the above you get a parametrization for the plane say,

$$g(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} x  \\ y ) \\ z(x,y) \end{pmatrix}$$

Now just take two different $p_i=(x_i,y_i)$ and form the correspond vectors $p_i - c = \textbf{X}_i$ where $i = 1,2$. Since you know the equation of the plane, you'll know how to pick $p_i$ so that $X_1,X_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: How is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197654/find-the-tangent-space-tcm-and-provide-a-basis-for-it different than this problem?

Comment: It's not. I just showed you why the gradient is a a normal vector $T_cM$. The other user says, $T_cM = \ker(Df(c))$. This is true due to the fact that $Df(c): T_cM \to T_{0} \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}$ and so $v \in \ker(Df(c)) \Rightarrow Df(c) \cdot v = 0$. Here $Df(c) = \nabla f(c)$. So you see, you still have to go through my construction to get the vectors though.

Comment: wait a second doesn't.. $\nabla f(c) = 3x^2+2y-2z=3(0)^2+2(1)-2(1)=0$?

Comment: @combostudent: You tell me the error in what you just wrote :). The gradient is a scalar?

Comment: oh ... Then the gradient is <$0,2,-2$> ?

Comment: Exactly. That's why I wrote $\nabla f(c) \not = \textbf{0} = (0,0,0)$.

Comment: Meaning it does not equal the zero vector, thank you

Comment: No problemo. Glad you figured it out. Keep working!